# React - Where is the change in order of Hooks?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const routes = [
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', children: <HomePage />, exact: true, strict: true },
    ...
]

const Wrapper = styled.div``

const Breadcrumbs = () =>
{
    const getRoutes = () => routes.filter(({ path }) => useRouteMatch({ path }))
    const getRouteMatches = () => getRoutes().map(({ path, name }) => ({ ...useRouteMatch({ path }), name }))

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            { getRouteMatches().map(({ url, name }) => <Fragment key={ url }>
                <Link to={ url }>{ name }</Link>
                <span>/</span>
            </Fragment>) }
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

This code is violating the React Rules of Hooks, because the order of Hooks is variable. Please help me understand why that error is occurring.

Firstly, I'm only using 1 type of Hook. So why does the order of Hook(s) matter if it's one Hook?

Also, does the React rule care about the *amount* of Hooks per render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple [hooks].

If you call a hook from a function other than the top level of your React function, there is the *possibility* that the order will be different.  The order of the hooks is necessary for React to know which state belongs to which hook between renders.

Answer (score 1):

`useRouteMatch` is used with the arrow function call, hooks can only be used directly within the component;

Answer (score 1):

Only call hook at top level. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

It helps React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls.

You need to move use of this hooks at top level instead of function calls.

```
    const getRoutes = () => routes.filter(({ path }) => useRouteMatch({ path }))
```